# C#: Open Excel (.XLSX) WorkBook => COMException

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I try to open a .XLSX file from VS2010 .NET 3.5 on a 64bit Windows 7.

Thats the code:

```
string fileName = string.Format("{0}\\test.xlsx", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());          

            Application _excelApp = new ApplicationClass();
            Workbook workBook = _excelApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
```

thats the error I get:

```
Old format or invalid type library. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80028018 (TYPE_E_INVDATAREAD))
```

What do I wrong, I go nearly crazy... I tried everything I think at least...

Comment: Google "0x80028018" and take the first hit.

Comment: I did Hans I did and yes my Office 2010 is english and my region settings in win 7 are austria. Then I set really everything to english /UK inclusive keyboard settings. Did a restart of the OS and run the project again. Same error!? WTF...

Comment: I'm at the same point. Have you found any solutions to the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on the code, but from working with excel on server-side in the past, you can get a lot of COM+ permissions errors that lead to this sort of error.  Check your event logs and go from there.